# java android handler calling

Tags: java, android

I am new in the android programming. I see many ways to do the event handling, but when I try to do it by calling the handler class it give error on handling class name:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //attach an instance of HandleClick to the Button
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new HandleClick());
    }    

    private class HandleClick implements OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Button btn = (Button)arg0;  //cast view to a button
            // get a reference to the TextView
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            // update the TextView text
            tv.setText("You pressed " + btn.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

`"HandleClick"` error come on this it say class should be abstract type?

I do not understand why it is giving this error can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

That's the wrong OnClickListener class. You have

```
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

You need:

```
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

For future reference, the error you get is "The type must implement the inherited abstract method...". This is because you need to implement the DialogInterface's onClick, which should have led you to notice that it was the wrong import (since you have `onClick(View)`)

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple & use this,

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
        "You have clicked Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
        tv.setText("You pressed " + btn.getText());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you imported the wrong OnClickListener, you should import the one from android.view.View